# java -- Two same Chinese Character are considered different

Tags: java, chinese-locale, string-comparison

I wanted a result of two trues come out for this piece of code, but I got one false and one true:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KFCG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input：");
        System.out.println("你好".contains(console.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("你好".contains("你"));
    }
}
```

On System.out:

```
input：你
false
true
```

Then I remembered I selected "Save as UTF-8" to save the code as UTF-8 when the system prompt me "some characters cannot be mapped using "US-ASCII" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supposed by the "US-ASCII" character encoding."

So I tried to encode the String from console to UTF-8, but still not work as my wish:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KFCG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input：");
        System.out.println("你好".contains(getUTF8XMLString(console.nextLine())));
        System.out.println("你好".contains("你"));
    }

    private static String getUTF8XMLString(String xml) { 
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
        sb.append(xml); 
        String xmString = ""; 
        String xmlUTF8= ""; 
        try {
        xmString = new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")); 
        xmlUTF8 = URLEncoder.encode(xmString, "UTF-8"); 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
        // return to String Formed 
        return xmlUTF8;
    } 
}
```

On System.out:

```
input：你
false
true
```

How can I get two trues? That is, how can I compare the Chinese character read from console and the character in program or in a .txt file?

Comment: Print the character codes of each string to see what the problem is: `Arrays.toString("你好".getBytes("UTF-8"))`, for example.

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting that output; you never display anything between "input:" and the first "contains()" method. Did you leave anything out? Right now it should put out something like "input:false" on one line, and "true" on the next.

Comment: Make sure your source files are in UTF-8.